# HDD bricked after hdparm --sanitize-overwrite (SG_IO: bad/missing sense data)

Tags: hdd, hdparm, secure-delete

On my HDD (WD RED Plus) I have performed SANITIZE using below command:

```
hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --sanitize-overwrite-passes 1 --sanitize-overwrite hex:11111111 /dev/sda
```

It was running fine, I saw the percentage kept increasing slowly in time (I ocasionally checked its status using --sanitize-status) and after some hours ~24 hours it was completed (at least I think it was completed). But now the disk is not usable (getting I/O error when doing fdisk /dev/sda for instance) and the --sanitize-status is giving me this info:

```
# hdparm --sanitize-status /dev/sda 

/dev/sda:
Issuing SANITIZE_STATUS command
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 00 00 21 04 00 00 80 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Sanitize status:
    State:    SD0 Sanitize Idle
```

When querying the info with hdparm -I I see the didk is not locked, frozen for instance:

```
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
    not supported: enhanced erase
    864min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
```

Is my disk dead now or can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: While googling I found information from some HP documentation "If a restricted sanitize operation fails, you are only allowed to start another sanitize operation, or, if the drive is under warranty, you can return it to HPE.". Therefore as my drive is anyway not usable I started new sanitize operation, this time in a different PC (but I doubt the issue is in the PC). When starting the sanitize again, there was no error and it shows progress:
`/dev/sdb:
Issuing SANITIZE_STATUS command
Sanitize status:
    State:    SD2 Sanitize operation In Process
    Progress: 0x378 (1%)
`

Comment: It did not help. The secound round of sanitize got completed till 100% (I logged the --sanitize-status each 1 minute so I have the progress in a log file). But after completing, the `SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 00 00 21 04 00 00 80 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` is again there. Btw I am using hdparm v9.65.

Comment: I really wonder why you use `hdparm` to erase a disk. This command is really dangerous and it seems you don't knew what you were doing. Would you please tell us more about your hard drive? How is it attached? What interface does it use? Model?

Comment: The hard drive is a SATA hard drive, standard rotational plates. The hard drive started having a lot of reallocated sectors, so it was failing. As the drive was anyway "dead" (who would use it when it has a lot of /over thousand/ reallocated sectors?) I wanted to test the hdparm's sanitize on it. According to the hdparm info, the disk supports this kind of operation so I do not see any reason why this should be considered as dangerous. I am just wondering why it throws the SG_IO error after completing of sanitizing... and whether it can still be "fixed".

Comment: How is it attached to the computer? Directly via mainboard SATA connector port?

Comment: PS `hdparm` was originally written to control/manipulate original PATA drives, it's a legacy program and it's not guaranteed to work without faults on new hardware like SATA - if the firmware of a SATA drive or the attached SATA controller is not correct emulating PATA (ATA/ATAPI) mode, using `hdparm` can destroy that drive

Comment: Also, it would help to know the exact hard disk drive model and the used SATA controller/mainboard.

Comment: Thanks for the comments with the hints! The HDD is attached to the mainboard directly using a sata cable (no usb to sata converter). But as the HDD was dead already (the reallocated sectors) I will stop investigating this issue. I was just a bit curious about why it happenned. I understood it in a way the sanitize overwrite feature is a HDD's firmware task - in case it is supported the HDD firmware will do the magic (what apparently was done as the progress went fine from 1 to 100%) and what I need is to wait till it is finished.